# Netbeans 8.2 sass argument --cache-location bug on Mac OSX

Tags: netbeans, sass

I install sass 1.15 with HomeBrew on Mac OSX .
I'd like to use the auto process of Netbeans 8.2 on saving but Netbeans add an deprecated argument  "/usr/local/bin/sass" "--cache-location" 
So impossible to use !

Can anyone can Help me ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: I created a bash script sass wrapper in my home bin directory that removes the first two arguments.  Since I never use additional command line options with sass I hardcoded the options as shown below.  You could create a loop through the options and and use case or if statements to pass all the arguments on to sass executable.  my file only has two lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/sass $3 $4 $5
```

make sure you make the file executable.

Answer (score 0):

You can fixed this issue with:

```
sudo gem install sass
```